# How to structure firebase firestore database?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am developing a react native(**Expo**) travel app in which the admin add all the places and destination category wise
my question is how can I add places category wise in Firestore in react native and how to add any data from the dropdown list to firestore>.

example:-

```
place => sate1=> city1 => category: heritage 
                          name:travelplaces1  
          
                 city2 => category:wildlife
                      name:travelplaces2

     state2 => city1 => cetagory:honyemoondestination
                        name:travelplacees1
```

**image of my app **

[image]

I am currently using  firebase javascript web SDK version 8 for this expo project

Comment: Structure of your database completely depends on the structure of your app. For example if users select a country before seeing all the places in this country, it would be smart to do a countries collection with all countries and then all the places for the country in there.

Comment: Do you have a coding question? Category is just another field in each document, like name and title.... so... what's causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the simplest structure I can think of would be to store all that data into a single document. So you can add all states, all cities, and all categories into separate arrays. That being said, in order to let the admin fill in the form, you'll always have to pay **a single document read**.

However, there are some limits when it comes to how much data you can put into a document. According to the official documentation regarding [usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> Maximum size for a document: 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

As you can see, you are limited to 1 MiB total of data in a single document. When we are talking about storing text, you can store pretty much. I doubt you'll reach the limitation but as your arrays get bigger, be careful about this constraint.